# background image resizing and repositioning not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, image-resizing

So i've got 2000x2000 px image and i want it to resize within different lenght monitors, here's what I did(don't mind the image link):

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns:svgjs='http://svgjs.dev/svgjs' width='1920' height='4000' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 1920 4000'%3e%3cg mask='url(%26quot%3b%23SvgjsMask1537%26quot%3b)' fill='none'%3e%3crect width='1920' height='4000' x='0' y='0' fill='url(%26quot%3b%23SvgjsRadialGradient1538%26quot%3b)'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3cpath d='M-79.38 2488.24L-79.38 2488.24' stroke='%23132e65' stroke-width='1.5'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M-79.38 2488.24L-45.34 2643.54' stroke='%23132e65' stroke-width='1.5'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M2036.36 2140.27L2036.36 2140.27' stroke='%23132e65' fill='%23132e65'%3e%3c/circle%3e%3ccircle r='5' cx='1895.54' cy='3665.24' fill='%23132e65'%3e%3c/circle%3e%3ccircle r='5' cx='2017.06' cy='3489.12' fill='%23132e65'%3e%3c/circle%3e%3ccircle r='5' cx='2061.31' cy='3665.29' fill='%23132e65'%3e%3c/circle%3e%3ccircle r='5' cx='2027.9' cy='3844.57' fill='%23132e65'%3e%3c/circle%3e%3ccircle r='5' cx='2019.91' cy='3954' fill='%23132e65'%3e%3c/circle%3e%3ccircle r='5' cx='1988.84' cy='4156.66' stroke-width='1.5'%3e%3c/path%3e%3cpath d='M1842.84 4003.3L1842.84 4003.3' stroke='hsl(228.5%2c 77.2%25%2c 51.5%25 fill='%238b9ad9'%3e%3c/circle%3e%3c/g%3e%3cdefs%3e%3cmask id='SvgjsMask1537'%3e%3crect width='1920' height='4000' fill='white'%3e%3c/rect%3e%3c/mask%3e%3cradialGradient cx='100%25' cy='100%25' r='4436.94' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' id='SvgjsRadialGradient1538'%3e%3cstop stop-color='%230e2a47' offset='0'%3e%3c/stop%3e%3cstop stop-color='rgba(0%2c 51%2c 158%2c 1)' offset='1'%3e%3c/stop%3e%3c/radialGradient%3e%3cradialGradient id='SvgjsRadialGradient1539'%3e%3cstop stop-color='white' offset='0.1'%3e%3c/stop%3e%3cstop stop-color='%231735b3' offset='0.2'%3e%3c/stop%3e%3cstop stop-color='rgba(23%2c 53%2c 179%2c 0)' offset='1'%3e%3c/stop%3e%3c/radialGradient%3e%3c/defs%3e%3c/svg%3e");    background-size: cover;
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Giorgi Chkhaidze | Junior Front-End Developer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

As you saw above, I tried to resize the background image with `background-size: cover;`, but it didn't work.

Comment: We need to see more of the context. How is body sized?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.